# How to add a node to a vector of lists?

Tags: c++, stl, adjacency-list

I am trying to implement an adjacency list using stl. I am trying to use a vector of lists:

```
std::vector<std::list<int> > graph;
```

My code to add an object to the graph is:

```
graph[size].push_back(8);  //8 is an example 
size++;
```

Every time I try to add a node I get a segmentation fault and I am not sure why. What is the correct way to add a node to this data structure?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a graph with adjacency lists, you could also go with an `unordered_map<std::list<int> > graph`.

Say, now you want to add a relationship between nodes a and b, then, all you would need to do is:

```
graph[a].push_back()
```

Adding a node would be simple:

find if the node exists, if it does not,then add it to graph:

```
iterator = graph.find();

if(iterator != graph.end())
{
    graph.insert(node);    

}
```

This would improve the find and insert time complexities.
now, both your find() and insert() are O(1) operations.

If you want to go ahead with `vector<list> graph`,

use `graph.push_back({x,y,..})`

Answer (score 0):

You have to allocate the vector using:

`std::vector<std::list<int> > graph(n, std::list<int>())`

Where `n` is the amount of nodes of your graph.

http://ideone.com/udJQrm